# How to Define which Calendar to Connect to using Google Calendar API v3 Service

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to list all the events in a certain public calendar in a nicely formatted manner on my web page without having a general/public visitor to my web site login or authenticate in any way. I have been doing this since December 2010 using v1 and the Zend Framework. On November 17, 2014 Google deprecated v1 and v2 and now my web page is broken.

**Here is what I've done so far:**

1. created a project in the Google Developer's Console
2. turned on Calendar API
3. installed PHP Client Library on my server from GitHub (yesterday - release 1.1.1)
4. ensured JSON PHP Extension is installed on my server
5. created OAuth 2.0 credentials
6. created Public API Access key
7. ensured my calendars are still publicly viewable (they have been since December 2010)

**Here is my code snippet:**

```
require_once 'autoload.php'; // 2014-11-24 part of /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("One_of_my_Calendars");
$client->setDeveloperKey("MY-PUBLIC-API-ACCESS-KEY"); // 2014-11-24 my Public API Access Key
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$results = $service->events->listEvents('primary');
```

**Here is the error message I am getting:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=MY-PUBLIC-API-ACCESS-KEY: (403) Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.' in /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:76 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(41): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #1 /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php(548): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2 /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(190): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #3 /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Servi in /usr/local/lib/php/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 76
```

**Screen Shots:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bytqhoir_Tt5ODRaNzRvS2FZRWs/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bytqhoir_Tt5MzlqLWF2Q3M2bUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you are missing the oauth2 part.  you need to be authenticated before  you can create a calendar service.

Comment: Ok @DalmTo but I thought I could do this via the Public API Access Key (the documentation seemed to allude to the 2 methods of getting the event list -- Public Access Key or OAuth 2.0). My web page / web service simply lists events to any public or general visitor out there from anywhere. I do want people to have to login in any way.

Comment: Oauth2 gives you access to another users calendar.  Using a service account will allow you to have one central calendar and display that information to others.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: All I want to do @DaImTo is list events from my public calendar in a nicely formatted manner on my web page. I have been doing this since December 2010 using v1 and the Zend Framework. Apparently, Google deprecated v1 and v2 on November 17, 2014 and now my web page is broken.

Comment: from my code above, how does Google know what calendar to pull from? Don't I need to specify which calendar to retrieve the events from @DaImTo? If so, how do you do that?

Comment: Its the authentication that tells google which calendar you have access to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65542/discussion-between-daimto-and-h-ferrence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are accessing public calendars (so no need for Oauth2), there are still two issues:

Issue no.1 you need to have a working API key from a project which has Calendar API enabled in the developer console.

Issue no.2 is your usage of the keyword "primary" without being authenticated. Replace it with the email address of the calendar that you want to access.

Comment: Issue 1 - I do have a working API Key and the Calendar API is enabled (turned on)

Comment: Issue 2 - I did change `primary` to the calendar's email address and got this error message: atal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/google%40example.com/events?key=MY-PUBLIC-ACCESS-KEY: (403) Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.'

Comment: see my screen shots @luc -- appended to my question

Comment: Try generating a new "Key for server applications" and use that one.